# Mysql query where condition with Date not equal to '0000-00-00'

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to write a mysql query in which the where condition is (WHERE date !='0000-00-00'). But the query is not executing properly.

```
WHERE date != '0000-00-00'
```

Comment: post your code ..  show a data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First cast date to char. then try.

```
WHERE CAST(`date` AS CHAR(10)) != '0000-00-00'
```

OR

```
WHERE `date` != 0
```

OR

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) != 0
```

OR

```
WHERE `date` IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
WHERE YEAR(`date`)=0
```

Comment: `WHERE `date` IS NOT NULL` i my case showed row with value `0000-00-00` . Column type was `date`. Storage Engine InnoDB, collation utf8_unicode_ci and used `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 3):

Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP in mysql Like Following :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) != 0
```

WHERE date is your column name..

Might This Will Helpful To You...

Answer (score 1):

In some cases mysql interpreted 0000-00-00 as NULL values. Can you try to select

```
WHERE `date` IS NOT NULL
```